# Como formatar números automaticamente como sobrescrito no Adobe InDesign CC 2021 usando GREP?

Tags: regex

Estou diagramando um livro no Adobe Indesign CC 2021 e sei que é possível usar estilos GREP (expressões regulares) para que a formatação aconteça automaticamente utilizando expressão regular.

O livro tem notas de fim de capítulo numeradas, e eu quero que os números dessas notas fiquem em sobrescrito. Mas há títulos que têm números no texto, então esses números não podem seguir os estilos GREP.

**Exemplo:**

*Do lado de cá3...* - O **3** tem que ficar sobrescrito

*Há 11 mil anos...* - **11 não** pode ficar sobrescrito

Eu tentei usar o código `\d\>`, onde `\d` localiza números e `\>` identifica que o número tem que estar no fim da palavra, mas com isso o InDesign aplicou o sobrescrito no segundo 1 em "11 mil anos".

Obrigado.

Comment: Seria interessante colocar a ferramenta/linguagem que está usando, pois cada uma implementa regex de um jeito e o que funciona em uma não necessariamente servirá em outra. Um ótimo exemplo é o `\>`, que não é suportado em muitas *engines*

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Estou usando a própria funcionalidade do Adobe InDesign que permite usar regex para aplicar formatação específica em textos que se aplicam a essa regra.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver o problema incluindo na regra que apenas números que não fossem antecedidos por outros números seriam formatados como sobrescrito:

`\d+\>` - Verifica se o último caractere da palavra é um número. O `+` certifica se o número acontece uma ou mais vezes.

`(?<=[\l\u])` - Verifica se antes do número que é o último caractere da palavra existe uma letra.

**Regra final:**
`(?<=[\l\u])\d+\>`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Não entendo nada sobre o InDesign, mas acho que posso de ajudar com a REGEX (expressão regular).

O grupo 1 da regex abaixo conterá apenas o número que for diretamente precedido por letras (incluindo as acentuadas):

```
[A-zÀ-Úà-ú]+([0-9]+)
```

Ou incluíndo apenas caracteres latinos:

```
\p{Latin}([0-9]+)
```

Veja a regex aqui: https://regex101.com/r/V767RA/1

Comment: Obrigado, mas a sintaxe no Adobe Indesign é um pouco diferente e essas regras não funcionaram. Mas eu vou tentar adaptar essa regra à sintaxe correta.

Comment: Tenta assim: [A-Za-zÀ-Úà-ú]+([0-9]+)